# This expression has type 'a list option but an expression was expected of type 'b list

Tags: list, ocaml

I am writing a function in OCaml that returns the longest list in a list using the type option and using `List.fold_right`.

```
let longest (lst : 'a list list) : 'a list option = 
  List.fold_right (fun (i : 'a list)  (y : 'a list option) -> if List.length i > List.length y then (Some i) y else y) lst None
```

However I keep getting the following error.

```
This expression has type 'a list option
but an expression was expected of type 'b list
```

The function should return `Some` followed by the longest list or `None` if it is empty.

Comment: Pattern match the list first. If empty return None, if `x::xs` return `Some ...` using x as initial element for your fold. No need to construct and match an option inside the fold every time and avoids your type error.

Comment: `let longest( lst : 'a list list) (x : 'a list option) = 
  match lst with
  | [] -> None
  | x :: xs -> Some ( List.fold_right  (fun i y -> if List.length i > List.length y then i else y) x xs)
 `         ` This expression has type 'a list list list
but an expression was expected of type 'a list
The type variable 'b occurs inside 'b list list `  I got this error however, when i tried to pattern match

Comment: You mixed up the arguments to List.fold_right, `x xs` should be `xs x`.

Comment: What is the unused `x` argument for longest for?

Comment: oh that is my bad the function was supposed to return 'a list option. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling [] as special case, dropping the unused `x` argument and reducing the number of times List.length is called to once per list I get this:

```
let longest lst =
  match lst with   
   | [] -> None   
   | x :: xs -> 
      Some (fst (List.fold_right
        (fun i ((y, ly) as p) ->
          let li = List.length i
          in
            if li > ly
            then (i, li)
            else p)
        xs
        (x, List.length x)));;

val longest : 'a list list -> 'a list option = <fun>
# longest [];;
- : 'a list option = None
# longest [[1]; [1;2;3]; [1;2]];;
- : int list option = Some [1; 2; 3]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to handle `[]` this way. `List.fold_right` already has a perfectly valid means of handling an empty list without writing extra code: it returns the initial value.

Comment: You don't want the accumulator to be an option type or you have to match it in every loop.

Answer (score 4):

Let's make this a bit easier to digest.

```
let longest (lst : 'a list list) (x : 'a list option) = 
  List.fold_right 
    (fun (i : 'a list)  (y : 'a list option) -> 
       if List.length i > List.length y then (Some i) y 
       else y) 
    lst 
    None
```

The specific issue this is complaining about is related to:

```
List.length y
```

In this situation `y` is supposed to be of type `'a list option` but `List.length` expects a value of type `'a list`.

You need to do some pattern-matching in the function you pass to `List.fold_right` to determine if the init value (in your code confusingly represented as `y`) is `None` or `Some ...` and then handle it accordingly.

It might look something like the following. Please note that the type annotations you've used are extraneous as OCaml will infer the types.

```
let longest lst =
  List.(
    let f x i =
      match i with 
      | None                                  -> ...
      | Some lst' when length x > length lst' -> ...
      | _                                     -> ...
    in
    fold_right f lst None
  )
```